# what button is pressed java

Tags: java, swing, events, button, actionlistener

there is possible to recognize whst btn is pressed with a unique  eventListener?

i tried this code, but didn't work

```
 ActionListener one = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (gr1.getCounter1() < 5) {
                        gr1.setCounter1(gr1.getCounter1() + 1);
                        if (arraybtn[1].isSelected())
                            test1.setIcon(play1a);
                        if (arraybtn[2].isSelected())
                            test1.setIcon(play1b);
                        if (arraybtn[3].isSelected())
                            test1.setIcon(play1c);
                        if (arraybtn[4].isSelected())
                            test1.setIcon(play1d);
                        if (arraybtn[5].isSelected())
                            test1.setIcon(play1e);
                    } else {
                        pn5.setText("No more cards");
                    }
                }
            };
```

thanks, !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code above is in great need of being refactored.  For instance you have an array of JButtons, why not a similar array of ImageIcons, then you could get rid of all those if blocks.

For instance:

```
  ActionListener one = new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (gr1.getCounter1() < 5) {
           gr1.setCounter1(gr1.getCounter1() + 1);
           for (int i = 0; i < arraybtn.length; i++) {
              if (arraybtn[i] == e.getSource()) {
                 test1.setIcon(play1Icons[i]);
              }
           }
        } else {
           pn5.setText("No more cards");
        }
     }
  };
```

And don't forget my recommendation in your other thread about further refactoring including creating a Player class, a Card class, a Deck class, a GameManager and so forth.

Regarding your question, "in this script i have play1a = hand.get(1).getImage(); if i do with another array like test1.setIcon(play1Icons[i]);, how i can define the variable?"

Is hand an ArrayList?  One way to solve it is to do something like

```
test1.setIcon(hand.get(i).getImage());
```

or some variant on that.

Comment: hi Hovercraft, i don't forget your suggestion :) in this script i have play1a = hand.get(1).getImage(); if i do with another array like  test1.setIcon(play1Icons[i]);, how i can define the variable? Thanks one more time

Comment: see edit in post above since it's so much easier showing code in answers than in comments.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for getting off on the wrong foot in the other forum.

Comment: no problem, you have helped me a lot, and I'm grateful for that

Answer (score 5):

use the `getSource` method from the `ActionEvent` object.

Your code would look like:

```
if (e.getSource() == arraybtn[1])
   test1.setIcon(play1a);
if (e.getSource() == arraybtn[2])
   test1.setIcon(play1b);
if (e.getSource() == arraybtn[3])
   test1.setIcon(play1c);
if (e.getSource() == arraybtn[4])
   test1.setIcon(play1d);
if (e.getSource() == arraybtn[5])
   test1.setIcon(play1e);
```

to get the source of the event (i.e. the button that was pressed).

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()

Comment: so you'd get

if(arraybtn[1].equals(e.getSource())) :-)

Comment: @hauntsaninja: he can use equals but there is no need since the above code is testing if one object reference is the exact same as another.